# snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 100016 (22000): Field delimiter ',' found while expecting record delimiter '\n' File line 178, Row 178

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load a csv file names F58155 to a table with the same name in snowflake. I have the file in csv format. And it is giving me the error in the title. I am also attaching the screenshot of the csv file line 178 where I am facing the issue(the rightmost column at the end). Can someone help?

```
import snowflake.connector
tableName='F58155'

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='*',
password='*',
account='*')

cs = ctx.cursor()

ctx.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE STORE_PROFILE_LANDING")
ctx.cursor().execute("USE SCHEMA PUBLIC")

ctx.cursor().execute("PUT file:///tmp/data/{tableName}/* @%{tableName}".format(tableName=tableName))
ctx.cursor().execute("truncate table {tableName}".format(tableName=tableName))
ctx.cursor().execute("COPY INTO {tableName} ".format(tableName=tableName))

ctx.close()
```

[image]

Comment: This clearly says there is issue with your file. Can you share the file format definition from snowflake ?  Can you run select on the file ? If the file is not big try to open it in an editor like sublime or notepad and eyeball that record to see anything unusual. Let me know.

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon The file is yet to be loaded into snowflake, so can't run select on file.

Comment: Can you try to put it to your stage. put file:///data/data.csv @%mytable; and then read it before loading. This will help us to debug the issue faster

Comment: Have you tried using snowflake's built in data load functionality?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might have a cell value that includes a comma. Something like:

```
1,2,3,"foo,bar",5,6
```

The COPY INTO statement has a FILE_FORMAT argument that you may want to experiment with to fit the nuances of your particular CSV file. For example, specifying...

```
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
```

... would help with the above example of a comma inside a cell value, but there could also be escaping issues, newline issues, etc that might produce the same error.

Docs are here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Another suggestion is to examine the CSV file with a text editor like VS Code that would help you spot something odd/unique about the row throwing the error. The problem might also be on the previous line.

Good luck!

Comment: 00112,GORDON'S INFO  ,HD US STORES   ,"HD US STORES (NO AK,HI,PR,VI)                               ",    ,  ,          ,   ,0.0,0.0,E,                                                                                                                                                                                                        ,0.0,N,116042.0,129365.0,A,ALISOND   ,X58155    ,ALISONDB  ,116042.0,132655.0,ALISOND   ,X58155    ,ALISONDB  ,116042.0,132655.0 This is the exact record where I am facing issue, i tried your method but no changes, still getting same error,      @Chris Sears

Comment: Can you share the code you used to try the parameter suggested with this answer?  It should have been a good solution or maybe the error changed?